# Using OpenGL 3.2 with Derelict3 and GLFW 3 on OSX Lion

Tags: opengl, osx-lion, d, opengl-3, glfw

I'm having trouble getting OpenGL 3.2 to run on Lion (osx 10.7.4) using Derelict3 and GLFW 3.

Here's my test program:

```
module glfw3Test;

import std.stdio, std.conv;
import derelict.glfw3.glfw3;
import derelict.opengl3.gl3;

string programName = "glfw3Test";
int width = 640;
int height = 480;

GLFWwindow window;

void main() {
    // load opengl
    DerelictGL3.load();
    // load GLFW
    DerelictGLFW3.load();

    if(!glfwInit()) {
        glfwTerminate();
        throw new Exception("Failed to create glcontext");
    }

    writefln("GLFW:     %s", to!string(glfwGetVersionString()));

    window = glfwOpenWindow(width, height, GLFW_WINDOWED, programName.ptr, null);
    if(!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        throw new Exception("Failed to create window");
    }

    // Request opengl 3.2 context
    // based off the GLFW FAQ: http://www.glfw.org/faq.html#4_2
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    DerelictGL3.reload();

    // Print OpenGL and GLSL version
    writefln("Vendor:   %s",   to!string(glGetString(GL_VENDOR)));
    writefln("Renderer: %s",   to!string(glGetString(GL_RENDERER)));
    writefln("Version:  %s",   to!string(glGetString(GL_VERSION)));
    writefln("GLSL:     %s\n", to!string(glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION)));
}
```

I get this output:

```
GLFW:     3.0.0 dynamic
Vendor:   NVIDIA Corporation
Renderer: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M OpenGL Engine
Version:  2.1 NVIDIA-7.18.18
GLSL:     1.20
```

I've checked, and it seems my graphics card should [support up to OpenGL 3.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_9_Series#GeForce_9M_Series).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All I had to do was specify some window hints *before* calling `glfwOpenWindow`:

```
...

glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

window = glfwOpenWindow(width, height, GLFW_WINDOWED, programName.ptr, null);

...
```

Answer (score 3):

Lion supports OpenGL 3.2. You need to specify OpenGL 3.2 core support at your code

See [OpenGL Profiles (Mac OS X v10.7)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_pixelformats/opengl_pixelformats.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH214-SW9)

and [Updating an Application to Support the OpenGL 3.2 Core Specification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/UpdatinganApplicationtoSupportOpenGL3/UpdatinganApplicationtoSupportOpenGL3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH3-SW1)

Comment: I see where is the problem. At derelict cgl.d, the code is from OS X 10.4. If you run glfw without Derelict with the snippet you provide, you get a correct OpenGL 3.2 context

Comment: Do you think this might be a problem with how I've compiled glfw3 on Lion? I tried a [simple C program](http://hastebin.com/banecacoce.coffee) where I specified the GL version and it couldn't load the window (the error was `The requested OpenGL version is unavailable`).

Comment: At the moment I generate GLFW's xcode project with CMake, then run `$ sudo xcodebuild -sdk macosx10.7 -target install`

Comment: Ok, I've fixed it! See my [answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11176097/679485).

Answer (score -7):

The problem is not with your videocard, but with OSX video drivers. OS X only supports OpenGL 2.1 and OpenGL ES 2.
You can consult [this table](https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/) for details

Comment: But didn't they begin to support it in 10.7.2+? If you switch to 'core' you get this: https://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/opengl/capabilities/GLInfo_1073_Core.html