# Why was OpenGl downgraded when I installed Mountain Lion?

Tags: xcode, opengl, osx-mountain-lion

**Edit:** Solved. This was a GLFW problem, not related to Mountain Lion or OpenGL.

I previously used Lion on my 2009 Macbook Pro. In XCode, the following worked without problems:

```
 glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);       
 glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
 glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
 glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_WINDOW_NO_RESIZE, GL_TRUE);
 glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

 ALLEGE(glfwOpenWindow(SCREEN_SIZE.x, SCREEN_SIZE.y, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW) != GL_FALSE);    // msg = "glfwOpenWindow failed. Can your hardware handle OpenGL 3.2?"

 int major, minor, rev;
 glfwGetGLVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
 fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL version recieved: %d.%d.%d\n", major, minor, rev);
```

And then printed `OpenGL version received: 3.2`. After I upgraded to Mountain Lion, the above code will not work (hangs up on the ALLEGE because glfwOpenWindow returns false). Stripping out all the GLFW window hints e.g.:

```
 ALLEGE(glfwOpenWindow(SCREEN_SIZE.x, SCREEN_SIZE.y, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW) != GL_FALSE);    // msg = "glfwOpenWindow failed. Can your hardware handle OpenGL 3.2?"

 int major, minor, rev;
 glfwGetGLVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
 fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL version recieved: %d.%d.%d\n", major, minor, rev);
```

allows the OS to select which version of OpenGL to use. The above code compiles and runs, but prints `OpenGL version received: 2.1` to the console.

I said, "wft?" and looked to the System Information app for more information. The Frameworks section informs me that the OpenGl framework I have is 1.8.6.

Now I'm all kinds of confused and rather upset if my OpenGL framework has indeed been downgraded. I know of no way to manually upgrade my framework. **Can anyone help me understand what's going on?**

**Edit1**: Using OpenGL Extensions Viewer.app informs me that my OpenGl version is `2.1 NVIDIA-8.0.61`

**Edit2:** the problem appears to be related to my project not using the correct profile (compatibility rather than core), but when I use glfw's hints to specify core e.g.

```
 glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

the subsequent call to `glfwOpenWindow()` fails. I don't know how to diagnose this problem because glGetError won't work until after the window has been successfully opened.

Comment: Mountain Lion didn't downgrade OpenGL. Most likely this is a problem where glfw is looking in the wrong place for the version.

Comment: Also see this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869647/using-opengl-3-2-with-derelict3-and-glfw-3-on-osx-lion?rq=1) for how to see OpenGL 3.2 features using glfw.

Comment: Thanks @KurtRevis, but the related question had the problem of not specifying which OpenGL profile to use. The line I used above, ` glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);`, is documented [here](http://www.glfw.org/GLFWReference27.pdf) to include the core profile. This method succeeded on Lion but now fails. I can't diagnose the problem using glGetError() due to bad access (I assume the context was not created when OpenWindow failed).

Answer (score 2):

Recompiling GLFW from source and using it with static linking only solved my problem. Some internal error was causing `glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);` to not work correctly.